# Using SharedPreferences to store application state

Tags: android, performance

I have a technical question regarding the use of **`SharedPreferences`**. I know that this component is supposed to be used to store the user specific preferences of the app (duh). I am currently developing a timer application and need some persistent information about the timer state (i. e. paused, started time, etc, etc.), and that information is not precisely user relevant or related.

I think using SQLite storage for this simple variables is an overload, because I would have a table with only one row, and the cursor management should be asynchronous because querying the information shouldn't be made in the UI thread.

Is there a better data structure to handle those persistent variables, or is it okay if I continue using the preferences?

The information can't be stored in a Bundle because it shouldn't be erased if the application stops running.

Comment: there's no problem if you keep it in sharedPref, just continue your job man

Comment: As you have only simple variables to store, I concur that SharedPreferences is the way to go. You should only use SQLite if you have multiple rows of similar data.

Comment: keep using shared preferences, there is no problem in that.

Comment: Thanks for resolving my question I can code relaxed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments already answered your question, but I'll provide some details.

Shared preferences are serialized and stored in an XML - for example for the `com.android.calendar` app it looks like this:

```
$ adb shell ls -la /data/data/com.android.calendar/shared_prefs/
-rw-rw---- u0_a6    u0_a6         126 2015-08-03 17:21 _has_set_default_values.xml
-rw-rw---- u0_a6    u0_a6         658 2015-08-05 23:05 com.android.calendar_preferences.xml
```

And the XML is serialized to look like this:

```
$ adb shell cat /data/data/com.android.calendar/shared_prefs/com.android.calendar_preferences.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<string name="preferences_week_start_day">2</string>
<string name="preferences_alerts_vibrateWhen">never</string>
<int name="preferred_startView" value="3" />
<boolean name="preferences_alerts" value="true" />
<boolean name="preferences_hide_declined" value="true" />
<string name="preferences_alerts_ringtone">content://settings/system/notification_sound</string>
<boolean name="preferences_home_tz_enabled" value="false" />
<string name="preferences_default_reminder">10</string>
<string name="preferences_home_tz">GMT</string>
<int name="preferences_default_cell_height" value="96" />
</map>
```

You can see how this is done by looking at the source of [`SharedPreferencesImpl`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java), which calls [`XmlUtils.writeMapXml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/XmlUtils.java#L182) to save the preferences...

See [line 636](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/util/XmlUtils.java#L636) to see how each value in the map is written in the XML.

Also see this question [Shared Preferences "limit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617825/shared-preferences-limit) where @CommonsWare warns that the entire XML file is read into memory so you wouldn't want to store "100KBS", I assume he means something like "hundreds of KBs". A reasonable arbitrary maximum is probably around a few hundred KBs.

So I'd say as long as the data you're storing is lightweight (i.e. is reasonable to be read/stored) as XML in the format listed above, you're OK and don't need Sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for the technical information, I will take the information about the limit into account to avoid abusing the preferences.