# How can I save the data my app parses, so that it doesn't need to be parsed when the app is reopened later?

Tags: java, android, json

So I am working on my app, and it parses data from the LoL (League of Legends) API, so far so good, but the only problem is that if the user closes the app, and reopens it parses the data again. I want the objects I parsed from the JSON data to be saved, once it initially parses them, instead of redownloading them every time I reopen the app. It slows my app down.

Comment: use a database to store your information, refer sqlite, realm

Comment: I was wondering if there is some native way in android to do this? Like the apps storage?

Comment: sqlite is a part of android to store data for offline use [refer here](https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do that, but they all basically doing the same thing: serialize/de-serialize objects. The difference will be mostly what kind of persistence storage and what serialization mechanism are you using.

As for persistence you can use for example file, data base, etc.

Java provides human-unreadable binary serialization. Instead you can use JSON, XML, etc. formats. I assume Java built-in serialization will be the fastest, but it won't be deserialize if your class changed in the mean time.

Local persistence also would allow to map objects you parsed into database and load them pieces by pieces as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Save your JSON data as a string in Android `SharedPreferences`. It is the most convenient and fastest method for you.

[Using SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: storing data in shared preference is not an efficient way

Comment: I am talking about this scenario. In this case shared preferences is faster than a sqlite db

Comment: please  check this answer by Commonsware   http://stackoverflow.com/a/15618511/6414107

Comment: @SaravInfern Thanks for the info. A small question. In an android device when you go to Settings -> Apps -> application details you can see a section App Data. What is meant by this data? Only the shared preferences or shared preferences + db

Comment: App data contains db , preferences , libraries,files and caches

Comment: SharedPreferences has a tight limit on the amount of data which can be stored in it.