# Saving large arraylists in shared preferences

Tags: android, gson, sharedpreferences

I just want to ask if it is good practice to save large array lists (of custom objects) in the Shared preferences using Gson.

By large I mean that the list might contain up to 500 object.

Comment: SharedPreferences are stored as XML and are basically meant to store small amounts of data. You should use a db instead, like SQLite. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617825/shared-preferences-limit

Comment: so you wouldn't recommend it to save lists in the shared preferences, is there any alternative to sqlite that spare me the time of creating tables and acceptes json objects like the shared prefs does immediately?

Comment: You could look at Realm: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest

Comment: Just put them in shared preferences. 500 entries is not much.  If you put them in a database you will need the same storage space from internal private memory. You could also save them to a file of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in android reference docs:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

> If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd
>   like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences APIs.

Else if you have a large amount of data the best solution is to use
file storage or sqlite or anything else.

Shared preference is made for store private primitive data types: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings, not arrays or complex objects.