# How to save Setting for next time?

Tags: android, android-activity, savestate

I am working on my application and I want to change the color of their UI with the click of button.....Like this....

```
Button change=findViewById(R.id.change_UI);
 change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //My code to change the color of UI
           //like blue to green-red-black etc (randomly)
        }
```

The above things are working fine but when I again restart my application all things were same as I open it first time...with blue color UI.

I am new for development and i know this question is not so much interested but please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: if i have more than 1 variable so is it work fine?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SharedPreferences` for this case. There is no problem for using it when you have more than 1 variable so don't worry.

Here is link to another answer how to use it properly: [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Another option could be creating one object which will hold all settings data and save it to a `file` and read it with every app run but for your case it would be overkill.

EDIT:
`SharedPreferences` data are stored in an XML file, a good practice would be not to store there more than `100kb`. If you want to store something bigger you SQL database like `Room` or save yout data to `file`.

More information you can find here: [Shared Preferences "limit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617825/shared-preferences-limit) or in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638736/6329985

Comment: okay thanks for your instant reply but is there any limit of storing data

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a preference activity as in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity).